# Internet connection in android emulator always displays connected state

Tags: android, internet-connection

I tried in many ways to check Internet connection in my android emulator

```
  ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  

   NetworkInfo info= conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();  

         if(info != null || info.isConnected()) {  
              Log.v("NetworkInfo","Connected State");  
         }  
        else{  
            Log.v("NetworkInfo","Not Connected state");  
            Log.v("Reason",info.getReason());  
        }
```

even if i disable Internet connection in my system ,my code  seems to display Connected state 
so i guessed this may work

```
 if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
        ||  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED  ) {

      Log.v("Congr","Connection Present");

    }
    else if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
        ||  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

      Log.v("conMgr"," No Connection");

    }
```

but the above code also displays "Connection Present" even when i disconnect Internet cables.
.Please help to find a correct way to do this .I have ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and INTERNET permission in my manifest file

Comment: Are you enabling/disabling the 3g connection in the emulator? You can do it pressing F8.

Comment: What happens when you put the emulated device into airplane mode?

Comment: The code  works when i put emulator into airplane mode .stackoverflow really rocks ,i never imaged to get an reply with mins of my post,thanks you Macarse and Jim.NetworkInfo info get null value when i put into airplane mode ,and i check  "info" for null value as done above and  alert the user about that .i haven't worked  in real device .Is this  method of checking Internet connection  is right ?

Comment: My experience with the emulator and network emulation is that it doesn't work as you might expect, and I discovered the airplane mode workaround by trial and error. As with so many platforms, getting good at Android is a lot of experimentation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*1* Disconnecting internet cables is irrelevant. Use F8 to switch off/on internet in the emulator

*2* In the first code this logic is wrong:

```
if(info != null || info.isConnected()) {  
              Log.v("NetworkInfo","Connected State");  
         }
```

It should be:

```
if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {  
              Log.v("NetworkInfo","Connected State");  
         }
```

If you use || then this is the result:
a) when info is null, info.isConnected() will crash
b) when info is not null, you will always show Connected State

However, even if you fix that, the code wont be completely correct (see *4*)

*3* In the second code, this logic is wrong:

```
 else if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
        ||  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

      Log.v("conMgr"," No Connection");

    }
```

should be:

```
 else {

      Log.v("conMgr"," No Connection");

    }
```

Why? Because there are more states than CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED.

However, even if you fix that, the code wont be completely correct (see *4*)

*4* This  works on emulator and devices.

```
connected = (   conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&
            conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()   )
```

Note the use of isAvailable - without this isConnected can return TRUE when WIFI is disabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. The "1. Use F8 to switch off/on internet in the emulator", made my day! I accidentally may have pushed it and was banging my head over it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this doesn't tell you if  the emulator is connected to the web via the hosting PC.   If you run it on a PC and the PC's wireless is turned off it still returns true as long the emulator thinks its in online state.    The only way I've been able to determine for sure whether the emulator is really online is to try to fetch a page and see if it succeeds or not.