# How to check connection to the internet (handle the Limited Connectivity case)

Tags: android

i used this code to check the internet connection

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

but it doesn"t handle the case when I have a limited connectivity to the internet, how to fix it ?

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/android-detect-if-device-has-internet-connection) .It shows how to check for active network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a web link programmatically in background if you get a success status then internet connection is available else if it fails there is no internet connection available. Try `HttpURLConnection` to check the internet availability by opening any link, you can get `HttpURLConnection` details in given link : [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: ok but I have a list view with different video streams to launch, 
so if the user clicks on a  item, I will always have to load an extra page and then load the video : it will take more time ... 
But if it's the only way to do it, I have no choice :p (maybe making a ping test will be faster ?)

Comment: It will be faster i guess so, and i am talking about ping test only using HttpURLConnection.