# Why can't the application launch this code?

Tags: android, connection

So I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/android-detect-if-device-has-internet-connection) here. 
But I can't get it to run since the isNetworkAvailable function isn't defined when calling it with a Context type parameter.
This is the code I used:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(ni!= null && ni.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean dostupanInternet(Context context)
{
    if(isNetworkAvailable(context))
    {
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection url = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            url.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
            url.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            url.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            url.connect();
            return(url.getResponseCode() == 200);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG","Povezivanje sa internetom nije uspelo",e);
        }
    }
    else
        {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Povezivanje sa internetom nije uspelo");
        }
    return false;
}
```

But when I run this it returns a fatal error and forces the application to shutdown.
So my question is - what is causing the fatal error (obviously an unhandled exception) and what code would get me past that internet availability check?

Comment: *what is causing the fatal error (obviously an unhandled exception)* The stack trace will tell you. Also make sure network operations are not done in the main (UI) Thread.

Comment: Also bear in mind that your code requires the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

Comment: I've added both ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and INTERNET permissions. Thanks for the help both of you

Answer (score 0):

Try use this method

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```