# Check if device has internet connection and then continue with code

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask

I was looking at the post:

[Detect if Android device has Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/android-detect-if-device-has-internet-connection)

and method for checking internet connection works fine, only thing that is bothering me is that i have to check that in background thread (cant check from the main thread)

what i need is to check if there is internet connection, and after i get answer i need to continue from that line of the code.

Problem is that if i check for connection in background thred (AsyncTask), main thred will make new thread and continue with compiling rest of the code.

Here is my code:

```
if(dbAdapter.doesDbExist(this)){
        Log.e("Da li baza postoji", "postoji");
        if(hasActiveInternetConnection(this)){
            new DownloadAllProizvodiTask(1).execute();
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.e("Da li baza postoji", "ne postoji");
        if(hasActiveInternetConnection(this)){
            new DownloadAllProizvodiTask(2).execute();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "U need internet connection to download resorces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

So i have to put method hasActiveInternetConnection() into asynctask, and when it finish, it has to continue from that if.

could someone give me some suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to rework the ordering of things to get it working with an AsyncTask. Your AsyncTask should look something like this:

```
new AsycTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
  @Override Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return hasActiveInternetConnection(...);
  }

  @Override onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(result) {
      new DownloadAllProizvodiTask(2).execute();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "U need internet connection to download resorces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      finish();
    }
  }
}.execute();
```

In your outer else, just start this task instead.