# Network online monitoring

Tags: android

There is a problem, I want to monitor internet connection.

There is good way with BradcastReceiver witch handles android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action. But this is not enough.

I want to know when internet is reachable. For example:
If I disconnect wan wire from the router, I want that my app notice it and tell me that I am "Offline" despite wifi is connected.

So, is there some default android solution, or should I make thread witch repeatedly ping to some host? Or maybe something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't do what you want. Connectivity could be broken anywhere on the Internet for some reason - you have no way to know this.

If you need to know whether you can reach a particular address then the only reliable way is to use a heartbeat signal - a Ping, or regular traffic on a persistent connection.

Comment: Not fully the truth: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/android-detect-if-device-has-internet-connection; though this might still not guarantee access to desired end points ... :)

Comment: Why that right answer is better than ping to same address?

Comment: @Trinimon The answers to your suggested question say pretty much what I said here.

Comment: @MartasSan Not all servers will respond to a ping, although they'll respond to a proper connection. HTTP is probably the most commonplace, but it's a bit heavyweight as it uses TCP - hence the suggestion for a persistent connection. Sending a UDP packet will be lighter if you have a responder available on the target machine.

Comment: @Mike W: my comment was related to "You simply can't do what you want." - the part which is not true ;) ... the linked answer gives some code nice in addition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no simple way to test if the Internet is reachable. You could repeatedly ping to some host but this is not a good practice. It's very battery inefficient approach. When your app makes a request and fails then you should consider that Internet is not reachable and show appropriate toast message, screen or whatever. Also I suggest you to look at some well written apps like Google Play Store and I see how they solve such problems. At least this is what I do :)