# InvocationTargetException when using FusedLocationProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I'm using `requestLocationUpdates()` from the `FusedLocationProvider` in android and setting it up `LiveData` and `ViewModel`. Here's what my code looks like:

**LocationLiveData.kt**

```
class LocationLiveData(context: Context) : LiveData<Location?>() {
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            super.onLocationResult(p0)
            p0 ?: return
            for (loc in p0.locations) {
                value = loc
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 60000
            fastestInterval = 10000
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            location?.also {
                value = location
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception ->
            Log.d("LocationLiveData", e.message ?: "FusedProviderClient Failed!")
            value = null
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                null
        )
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }
}
```

I'm observing this in a fragment like so:

```
userAuthVM.locationUpdates.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
    if (it != null) {
        userLoc = geocoder.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1)[0]
    }
})
```

Sometimes I get this error which I don't really understand:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.halalrishtey, PID: 14048
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        at com.halalrishtey.RegisterFragment$onViewCreated$1.onChanged(RegisterFragment.kt:35)
        at com.halalrishtey.RegisterFragment$onViewCreated$1.onChanged(RegisterFragment.kt:19)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:289)
        at com.halalrishtey.viewmodels.LocationLiveData.access$setValue(LocationLiveData.kt:13)
        at com.halalrishtey.viewmodels.LocationLiveData$onActive$1.onSuccess(LocationLiveData.kt:40)
        at com.halalrishtey.viewmodels.LocationLiveData$onActive$1.onSuccess(LocationLiveData.kt:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you running this code on some emulator ? if so then try to use a physical device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.IOException: grpc failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012289/java-io-ioexception-grpc-failed)