# Android java.io.IOException: grpc failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Google Maps for my Android application and sometimes (I have tested in emulator and real device) I get the following error when I call the method `geocoder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);`

I have tried solutions like running the code in another thread but it doesn't work

```
W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
        at com.example.fragments.Mapa.getMyLocations(Mapa.java:198)
        at com.example.fragments.Mapa.onMapReady(Mapa.java:132)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
W/System.err:     at fv.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):14)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):4)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bk.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):4)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: This question has been discoursed  before, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012289/java-io-ioexception-grpc-failed

Comment: @DigitShifter nothing works in what you've referred to sir.