# Android data upload

Tags: php, android

I am new to mobile development and still have much to learn. I have written an Android application that collects user data in SQLite database locally. I would like this data to be uploaded separately to users actions, which means:

- When the user is using the application, all of the data is stored locally,
- If the user has internet connection, data can be uploaded immediately to data server (no problem about the server side, php scripts are already written for data insertion),
- If the user has no internet connection, the application will wait for any connection and then upload the data.

I would like to know, what is the best approach to do this - is it any kind of service running in the background, or anything else? I have read about services only in tutorials, so I don't know exactly how to deal with them and if I should even bother writing them, to achieve what I have mentioned above?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually services are not so necessary for that (Example: if you have only one activity). Service helps you keep off thread work apart of activity lifecycle. Ok. Now, decision of your problem step-by-step:

1. You need to create off thread work (AsyncTask, Thread etc.), which tries to send you data to server
2. If it fails you can use ["connection changed" listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener) of just schedule your next try with Handler.postDelayed
3. Service only helps you to keep control of that off thread work from different activities if you need that

Comment: I have many activities, does it change anything?

Comment: Yes, you should use Service :) Bind and unbind it in activities, if you need result to be shown to user