# Internet is off initially, Is there any On Internet Connected Event which can be subscribed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Looking forward to sync up data when app is connected to internet, through either WIFI or Mobile data.

Suppose internet was off initially, when internet is connected:

> Is there any OnInternetConnected Event in android which we can
>   subscribe to?
>   What is equivalent to handle similar scenario?

EDIT:

> The proposed links suggests checking internet access. If we follow
>   other answer we need to keep polling the device for internet
>   connectivity,
>
> Looking for an event handler to hook into, rather than polling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678314/3023833