# How to update network type on TextView each time network changes?

Tags: android, textview

Helo. I'm very new to android programming. I have the following code to show in a TextView the current network type. The code it works but when I change the network type the TextView is not updated. I even tried with a `Toast` and is not updated either.

How to make the TextView shows the network type each time is changed in handset?

I'm trying in Android 6.0.1.

```
package com.example.getnettype;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        TelephonyManager teleMan = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = teleMan.getNetworkType();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(networkType),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (networkType)
        {
            case 0:  mTextView.setText("Unknown"); break;
            case 1:  mTextView.setText("GPRS");    break;
            case 2:  mTextView.setText("EDGE");    break;
            case 3:  mTextView.setText("UMTS");    break;
            case 13: mTextView.setText("LTE");     break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener

Comment: @BlindKai Thanks for the suggestion. Where in my code should I include the Broadcaster receiver? may you show me some example please.

Comment: Sure. It's not a problem. You also could check the @ArkaPravaBasu comment. It should give you some ideas.