# "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort" For no particular reason 30 seconds after socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

I am facing a strange issue with Android's airplane mode and a `Socket` exception 30 seconds after opening a new `Socket` connection.

Here's what I do on my app that creates an issue:

1. Have an opened `Socket` connection and turn on and off airplane mode.
2. Reopen a new `Socket` connection with the server.
3. Wait 30 seconds and get a `java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort` on a `DataInputStream` `readByte()` call.

I have checked my server logs and the server is not disconnecting the client.

Does anyone know what could cause this? I've browsed other posts with the same exception, but they all had a more detailed error message. I can also send and receive messages with that `Socket` connection fine for 30 seconds, but then it randomly throws an exception.

Comment: The data connection pipe is effectively broken when you toggle airplane mode so you will have to re-establish the connection again

Comment: @Rafsanjani Yes, I catch the initial exception when airplane mode is turned on. I close the socket connection and close the data streams. Then, when airplane mode is off, I make a new socket, connect it to the server, and then make the new data streams from the socket.

Everything seems to work fine. After I get the exception 30 seconds after reconnecting after turning off airplane mode, I try to reconnect and then the connection works fine. I really don't get it.

Answer (score -1):

i think to mange this case , opening airplane mode and turning of you should make listener 
for internet connection and when internet state change to there is connection rebuild your socket and when state changed to no internet  close the socket 
    you CAN find an example on Internet connectivity change listener [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener)