# How to display a message in case of no connection

Tags: android

is there a solution for a popup to appear **on all the pages** of the application if the user does not have an internet connection ?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Internet connectivity change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener)

Comment: it's in java, I want to do it in Kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422512

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an activity with an error message. So whenever there's no internet connection then show them no internet connection activity. You can also give a message in a toast or snack bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
fun isNetworkConnected(context: Context) : Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val capabilities =  connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
    capabilities.also {
        if (it != null){
            if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI))
                return true
            else if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)){
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

you can check internet connection every where you want.

```
    if(isNetworkConnected()){
     // do something
     }

    else{
     // use toast or a dialog to say internet is not connected
     }
```

and don't forget to add this permissions to manifst

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i get : 'getter for activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java 'getter for isAvailable: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java 'getter for isConnected: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java 'getter for isFailover: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java 'getter for isRoaming: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java –

Comment: @admindunet check sol again