# Refresh webview after internet connection on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to refresh a WebView after regaining internet connection, I have a try again button. If we click on it, the URL will be loaded again. But with the code I've written, this feature is not working.

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private LinearLayout NoInternetLayout;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_horizontal);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.SwipeRefresh);
        NoInternetLayout=findViewById(R.id.NoInternetLayout);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.Webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        chekInternet();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }


    private void chekInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi=connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile=connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isConnected()){
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NoInternetLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (mobile.isConnected()){
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NoInternetLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            NoInternetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

          chekInternet();
            Button newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    chekInternet();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

        android:id="@+id/SwipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/Webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/NoInternetLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/refresh"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:src="@drawable/nointernet" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to listen for internet connection, by referring [algrid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58468010/7948109)
use `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` for API >= 24 (and `registerNetworkCallback` for API < 24)

```
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        // network available
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(Network network) {
        // network unavailable
    }
};

ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
        (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
} else {
    NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET).build();
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback);
}
```

In `onAvailable()` you can call reload/refresh using these 2 ways

```
webView.loadUrl(mWebView.getUrl().toString());
```

or

```
webView.reload()
```

Comment: @hata I have updated my answer and rectified my mistake

Comment: I think it's ok now :)