# can we check internet connectivity of connected device with appium java

Tags: appium

I am new to appium and started writing some basic scripts with java. I need a code which will check the device internet connectivity on which test going to perform.

This will be basic test before starting the actual test. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe you take [the tour first](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I know the question specifically asks for an appium solution, but it may be better to try something slightly different.

Would be better to leverage `adb shell dumpsys connectivity | grep NetworkInfo`? You can then inspect the connectivity to the internet (CONNECTED state). 

For example, you may see a line similar (may be different for different devices) to: `NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED,`... I think you can also inspect `UMTS` NetworkInfo as well if that is relevant.

Go ahead and test it on your device.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can verify the device internet connectivity directly from appium. However you can prepare small apk (I assume you use the Android device) that will verify that , see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection).
Or you may launch some browser (like Chrome) on the device  and verify that the online page is received.