# Google API Client connect method is freezing the UI when no Internet connection

Tags: android, google-api

I read in the documentations that the connect method "returns immediately, and connects to the service in the background." But I don't think it's the case, at least for me.

I even create a separate thread for the connect method but the UI still freezes every time onStart method (where I'm trying to connect) is called.

NOTE: This happens only when there is no internet connection.

So how do I get around this? Thanks

Comment: why are you calling connect when there is no internet. Before calling connect method first check if internet is available or not

Comment: Yea. I'm checking it via the ConnectionManager. But by saying "no internet connection", I mean connection could be very slow. Or that the user is connected to a network/wifi but the wifi itself has no internet connection.

Comment: Or could you give me a better way to check the internet connection? Thanks.

Comment: Seee this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection

Comment: I had a similar issue. Do not create instance of GoogleApiClient if there is no internet. wrap instantiation in if(isInternet()){} and don't forget to annotate   mGoogleApiClient with @Nullable

Comment: I am having a similar problem. By looking at the general logs, I can see an exception after 2 minutes (!) and the client still hanging there.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Can you provide logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Like said above check whether the you have internet connection..!!

```
 private void CheckConnection() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                answer="You are connected to a WiFi Network";
            System.out.println(answer);
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                answer="You are connected to a Mobile Network";
        }
        else
            answer = "No internet Connectivity";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

In Manifest File add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

if in Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting() || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

and In **Oncreate function**

```
 //Initializing googleApiClient
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
```

in Service class do the above on **Oncreate**.