# Android Internet Connection timeout

Tags: java, android, android-internet, android-connectivitymanager

I'm able to detect Internet connection using

```
public class InternetDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public InternetDetector(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible internet providers
     **/
    public Boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    public Boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
            int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
            return reachable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly if there is internet, but in some cases I am able to connect to WIFI but no internet. In this case If internet is not available I nned to show a message[No INTERNET CHECK YOUR CONNECTION] to user after 10 seconds

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        // Your message here
    }
}, 10000); //Your time here in miliseconds
```

After the time is completed the message will be displayed to user. Simple is that.

For 10 seconds you can add 10000

Comment: Thanks for your comments, let me try this.

Comment: @ChandraMouliPoreddy Sure buddy , and if it worked then dont forget to accept and rate up the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following to check for internet connectivity and therefafter show a toast in case there is no internet :

```
boolean isInternetAvailable = checkInternetConnection(this);

    if(!isInternetAvailable) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No INTERNET CHECK YOUR CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, 10000);
    }

    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetworkInfo != null) { // connected to the internet
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetworkInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
                return isWifiInternetAvailable();
            } else if (activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public boolean isWifiInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can check if you are connected to the `wifi` or `Cellular Network` but you cannot easily check if you are really connected to the `Internet` or not.

Right now the only way to check if you are really connected to the internet is to connecting to a remote server! for example:

```
public static boolean hasInternetAccess(Context context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) 
                (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                .openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                        urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can change URL to any desired address but this URL generate a determined response so you don't have to worry about server problems.. Of course you can Change it to your server to check availability of server too ^^

For more info you can check this answer:
[Detect if Android device has Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection)