# When checking internet access in android, why does it always return "true"?

Tags: android

How to check for Internet access in Android?

Why does it always return `true`?

I am sure I am not connected to Internet. Why does it return `true`?

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
        cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&
        cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in your manifest?

Comment: yes.I written in manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try testing to figure out which connection is seen as active:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo netInfoMob = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_MOBILE);
  NetworkInfo netInfoWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_WIFI);
  if (netInfoMobile != null && netInfoMobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    Log.v("TAG", "Mobile Internet connected");
    return true;
  } 
  if (netInfoWifi != null && netInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    Log.v("TAG", "Wifi Internet connected");
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Edit: On the emulator, it will always show mobile connected regardless of your computer's Internet connection. Use F8 to switch it off, as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937915/560092

Comment: 07-08 14:36:01.069: V/TAG(2281): Mobile Internet connected.
 i use emulator.My laptop is not connected to the Internet .Why does this happen?

Comment: Ah, the emulator is always "connected", I think. Use F8 to switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        if(!isAvailable) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Comment: This returns true as there is net access, but it doesn't mean we are authorized ... sadly there is no API to check that it seems like something like pinging google or something like that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using doesn't always work correctly. Some times it will return true even if you are connected to a wifi network (but that network isn't actually connected to internet), etc. The other alternative is

```
public boolean isOnline() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo netInfoMob = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_MOBILE);
  NetworkInfo netInfoWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_WIFI);
  if ((netInfoMobile != null && netInfoMobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (netInfoWifi != null && netInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
    return true;
}
  return false;
}
```